Making a scatterplot in SPSS showcasing before/after effects with a distinct colored line connecting each observation before and after?
I seldom use SPSS and am trying to recreate a chart that I made in R in SPSS.
I have a dataset that looks at emotion and problem-based scores for 15 patients pre-intervention and post-intervention.
ID={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},

Pre_Post={Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre, Pre,
          Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post, Post},

Emotion={1, 4, 2, 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 
         2, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 6, 11, 10}, 

Problem_Based={2, 4, 3, 2, 10, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 1, 6, 2, 11, 8,
               5, 10, 5, 6, 2, 9, 10, 7, 6, 9, 5, 8, 4, 20, 15}


I am trying to make a chart with a different colored line for each ID connecting their pre-and post emotion-based scores and problem-based scores with a distinct shape at the end of each line designating whether the score is pre- or post-intervention. For example, in R I made this graphic:

In SPSS syntax window, I wrote this
graph/
    scatterplot(bivar)=Problem_Based with Emotion by Pre_Post.

and got this

But how do I connect these with distinct colors for each ID and a different shape or distinct color for pre-and post intervention? Any suggestions for how I can recreate the R image as much as possible in SPSS would be much appreciated, thank you.
